# post request 404 NOT FOUND after hosting website

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I just hosted a website with Network Solutions and when I try to use the contact form on the site, a 404 error appears. I am aware that something is not configured correctly. What do I need to change in my code? I use Node.js and React.

Error: POST http://www.example.com/api/contact 404 (Not Found)

Port 80 doesn't work...

My index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const { contact } = require('./contact');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    const path = require('path');
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}

app.post('/api/contact', contact);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Do I need to change the PORT code to something else?

Comment: Change port to 80 or use http://www.example.com:3001/api/contact

Comment: I tried but I get the same error message

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of how Network Solutions works but the problem is most probably is your port. Check out what is the process.env.PORT (from node console.log) and if it is in 3001 port make sure that port is accessible and not blocked by firewall.